# IIS Redirect Root Domain Name To Sub Domain Web App

Tags: .net, redirect, iis

I have a web site configured via IIS as follows...

http://domain.co.uk/webapp/default.aspx

Using the above link works fine and navigates to my web app homepage, but if I navigate to http://domain.co.uk I just get a generic MS IIS landing page. How can I redirect the plain domain address to the full web app path?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

you could try below mentioned rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.co.uk/webapp/default.aspx" />
            </rule>
```